# What is the precise definition of the complement of subgraph $H$ in $\overline G$?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a simple graph and $H$ be a subgraph of $G$.
Then, what is the definition of the complement of $H$ in $\overline G$?
I have got the question from a proof of the Nordhaus-Gaddum Theorem(the link is [https://books.google.ca/books?id=*l4CJq46MXwC&pg=PA185&lpg=PA185&dq=Nordhaus-gaddum+Theorem&source=bl&ots=BKEqxLnkg*&sig=dlT_-zR38Wc_GNdY50fAaqV6w_c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwisx77t8b_YAhUFzGMKHTKhBc44ChDoAQhLMAU#v=onepage&q=Nordhaus-gaddum%20Theorem&f=false](https://books.google.ca/books?id=_l4CJq46MXwC&pg=PA185&lpg=PA185&dq=Nordhaus-gaddum+Theorem&source=bl&ots=BKEqxLnkg_&sig=dlT_-zR38Wc_GNdY50fAaqV6w_c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwisx77t8b_YAhUFzGMKHTKhBc44ChDoAQhLMAU#v=onepage&q=Nordhaus-gaddum%20Theorem&f=false)). For your information, I knew the definition of the complement of $H$ with respect to $G$.

Comment: Can you point out exactly where the line you're talking about occurs?

Comment: It is in the second sentence of the last paragraph at page 185.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just asserting that there is a graph, $H'\subseteq\overline{G}$, such that $H'$ is the complement of $H$ (hence why they use $\overline{H}$ as the notation for this graph). It is the complement of $H$ inside of $G$, but the graph itself is a subgraph of $\overline{G}$.

Does that clear things up?

Comment: I think your answer is not about the complement of $H$ in $\overline G$.

Comment: @kswim I've changed my answer, please see it and give me feedback

Comment: You meant not $\overline H$, but $\overline G$ at the last sentence right before the questioning sentence in your answer, do you?

Comment: @kswim Yes, that's fixed now.

Comment: Thank you for helping me clearly understand the proof :)